# Mostrar a hora UTC em um Entry Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

eu gostaria e estava tentando uma forma de mostrar a hora, se atualizando sozinha, por meio de um entry no tkinter. Montei uma função para isso mas não consigo fazer com que ela apareça no Entry, em vez disso aparece "function UTClock at..". Como pode ser observado na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O codigo para gerar a imagem acima foi esse:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

root = tk.Tk()

def UTClock():
    hora_UTC = timezone('Greenwich')
    uTC_hora = datetime.now(hora_UTC)
    curr_utc = uTC_hora.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    horaUtc.after(100, UTClock)

#Configurando a caixa do sites
caixadosite = tk.LabelFrame(root, text=' aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ', font=("Arial",14))
caixadosite.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=8, pady=4, sticky=N, columnspan=3)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



#Configurando a caixa do nascer do sol e sua entrada
ttk.Label(caixadosite, text="hora: ", font=("Arial",14)).grid(column=3, row=0, columnspan=3)
horaUtc = tk.StringVar()
horaUtcEntry = ttk.Entry(caixadosite, width=25, state='readonly', justify='center', textvariable=horaUtc, font=("Arial",14))
horaUtcEntry.grid(column=3, row=1, columnspan=3)


horaUtc.set(UTClock)


root.mainloop()
```

Eu gostaria que a hora aparecesse no Entry e atualizasse sozinha, mas to batendo cabeça com isso há um tempo. É possível? Agradeço toda a ajuda.

Comment: Duas coisas:
1. dentro de sua função `UTClock` tem uma variável (`horaUtc`) que não foi inicializada. Lembre que python trabalha com escopo de variável
2. Acredito que vc deveria chamar a função ao invés de referenciá-la => `horaUtc.set(UTClock())`
Mesmo assim, ainda acho que falta trabalhar o código um pouco mais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

root = tk.Tk()

def UTClock():
    hora_UTC = timezone('Greenwich')
    utc_hora = datetime.now(hora_UTC)
    curr_utc = utc_hora.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    return curr_utc


#Configurando a caixa do sites
caixadosite = tk.LabelFrame(root, text=' aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ', font=("Arial",14))
caixadosite.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=8, pady=4, sticky=N, columnspan=3)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#Configurando a caixa do nascer do sol e sua entrada
ttk.Label(caixadosite, text="hora: ", font=("Arial",14)).grid(column=3, row=0, columnspan=3)
y = tk.StringVar() 
horaUtcEntry = ttk.Entry(caixadosite, width=40, state='readonly',
justify='center', textvariable=y, font=("Arial",14))
horaUtcEntry.grid(column=3, row=1, columnspan=3)
y.set(UTClock()) #O que faltou no seu codigo

root.mainloop()
```